# Mock function is returning null value, instead of giving mock value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I want to write test case on following function

```
public async Task<List<Author>> GetAuthor()
            {
                using IDbConnection db = GetDbconnection();
    
                var result = await Task.FromResult(dapperWrapper.GetAll<Author>(db, $"SELECT TOP (10) liAuthorId as Id, sFirstName as FirstName, sLastName as LastName from dbo.Authors", null, commandType: CommandType.Text));
                return result;
            }
```

I am trying to mock GetAll method inside the GetAuthor method and passing mock value in return of that function but when I am trying to run the test method GetAuthor, GetAll method is giving null value ,inspite of giving the mock value given in return function.

```
 public async Task TestMethodTestAsync()
        {

            var expectedConnectionString = "url";
            using IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(expectedConnectionString);
            var expectedQuery = $"SELECT TOP (10) liAuthorId as Id, sFirstName as FirstName, sLastName as LastName from dbo.Authors";
            List<Author> author = 
                new List<Author> {
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" },
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" },
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" },
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" },
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" },
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" },
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" },
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" },
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" },
                new Author { Id = 1, FirstName = "abc", LastName = "def" }
               };

            mockDapperWrapper.Setup(x => x.GetAll<Author>(db, expectedQuery, null, CommandType.Text)).Returns(author);

            var result = newsRepository.GetAuthor();
```

Author Model

```
  public class Author : BaseModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As I just started learning C# and new to this, Please let me know ,if I am doing any mistake.

I want to write test case on following function

```
public async Task<List<NewsArticle>> GetNewsArticle()
    {
        // Create SQL Connection
        using IDbConnection db = GetDbconnection();

        // Create Dapper dynamic parameter set
        DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();

        // Output Paramaters
        parameter.Add("@ReturnValue", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        parameter.Add("@Message", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 400);

        var result = await Task.FromResult(dapperWrapper.GetAll<NewsArticle>(db, $"[KafkaPublisher].[GetNewsArticle]", parameter, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));
        
        return result;
    }
```

I am trying to mock GetAll method inside the GetNewsArticle method and passing mock value in return of that function but when I am trying to run the test method GetNewsArticle , GetAll method is giving null value ,inspite of giving the mock value given in return function.

```
 public async Task Should_Fetch_NewsArticle_Data()
    {

        DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();

        // Output Paramaters
        parameter.Add("@ReturnValue", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        parameter.Add("@Message", dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: 400);
        string expectedQuery = "[KafkaPublisher].[GetNewsArticle]";

        List<NewsArticle> article =
            new List<NewsArticle> {
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1 },
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1 },
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1 },
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1 },
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1 },
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1 },
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1 },
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1 },
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1 },
            new NewsArticle { Timestamp = 1, Version = 1, Headline = "hl", Body = "b1", AuthorId = 1

            };

        mockDapperWrapper.Setup(x => x.GetAll<NewsArticle>(It.IsAny<IDbConnection>(), expectedQuery, null, CommandType.Text)).Returns(article);

        var result = await newsRepository.GetNewsArticle();
```

Comment: Mocking databases at this low level is generally a bad idea. Either use a real database for integration testing (like a LocalDB instance) or abstract the databases access a bit so you can mock methods returning domain objects (in other words, mock `GetAuthor` itself, not its implementation). Something like `GetAuthor` is not generally worth testing on its own because it's trivial; the test would never reflect anything more or less than the method's implementation, and both would have to change in lockstep, which eliminates the usefulness of the test. Expecting a specific query is a bad sign.

Answer (score 2):

Mock will return configured value only when all arguments matching. The `db` value passed into mock setup is different from one created in `GetAuthor`. Use `It.IsAny<IDbConnection>()` for mock setup to match any argument of this type.

Comment: Thanku Artur ,it works and one thing I want to know more in case of store procedure ,how it works.I have updated the question with method invoking store procedure.Please help me in this

Comment: Read @JeroenMonstert comment. Don't mock your DB, it useless. Mock your DAL in unit tests and perform integration tests against real DB to test your DAL